# How to represent a list of custom objects using Xml Serialization

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I want to produce the following xml output

```
<account>
    <id>123456</id>
    <roles>
        <role master-name="I80">
            <id>88</id>
            <unit>Implementer</unit>
        </role>
        <role master-name="S20">
            <id>21</id>
            <unit>Support</unit>
        </role>
    </roles>
</account>
```

So I create the following class

```
[XmlRoot("account")]
public class Account
{
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("roles")]
    public RolesList Roles { get; set; }
}

public class RolesList
{
    [XmlElement("role")]
    public List<Role> roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    [XmlAttribute("master-name")]
    public string MasterName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("id")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("unit")]
    public string Unit { get; set; }
}
```

My question is, Is there a way to represent this any better?  I want to avoid creating the RolesList class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare the list of roles like this in `Account`:

```
[XmlArray("roles")]
[XmlArrayItem("role")]
public List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
```

Comment: I will try that, but I think XArrayItem will produce the element <Role> instead of <role> (lowercase)

Comment: @KishoreMasand: have you tried it out? I had tested it, and it seemed to work correctly.